# Is there a way of making the baseline from a complex mesh horizontal keeping it clean?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, 3d-printing, subdivision-surface

[image]
I want to make the model of a turtle for printing it, and in the process, I found easier to have a clear base, because I thought of printing it apart, but I don´t know how to correctly make all the extremes horizontal without messing up the mesh, I tried selecting with edge loop the border, and scaling it to 0 in Z axis, also with proportional editing activated ("o" hotkey), but it ends up looking pretty distorted, and I don´t think that´s going to look well printed.

For the model, I used a plane, subdivided it, extrude individual faces, apply subdivision surface, smooth, and then a lattice modifier, applied them and after that used the proportional editing.

Comment: Is the shell a separate piece of the model, or is it connected to the head? I can't tell from the picture.

Comment: Yeah, it´s a separate piece, I made it other way.

Comment: That's good, it'll be easier to mess with. What happens when you try to scale it to zero, and does it still look bad if you hide the other objects?

Comment: I think the other objects don´t necessarily have something to do with my problem because I didn´t join them. I´ve found a modifier called smooth, and it´s cleaning up a little the mesh, but I lose some details, obviously.

Comment: I wouldn't use smooth, then. What does it look like if you select the bottom loop, extrude downward, scale 0 on Z, and then `F` to make a face?